# Make search query using KVP return results when some search attributes are not supplied

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help regarding a complex SQL query that successfully runs, but needs to validate an extra step in order to provide reliable results.

These are the main 3 tables involved in this query:

```
RULE
rule_id   rule_set_name   status   position   date_from   date_to
1         B2C             1        1          null        null
2         England All     1        2          null        null


RULE_ATTRIBUTE
attribute_id   attribute_code
1              customer_group
2              customer
3              country
4              subdivision_one
5              subdivision_two

RULE_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
value_id   attribute_id   store_id   rule_id   value   parent_group_id   parent_country_id   parent_subdivision_1_id
9          1              0          2         0       null              null                null
10         1              0          2         1       null              null                null
11         1              0          2         2       null              null                null
12         1              0          2         3       null              null                null
13         1              0          2         4       null              null                null
14         1              0          2         8       null              null                null
15         1              0          2         9       null              null                null
16         3              0          2         34      null              null                null
17         4              0          2         540     null              34                  null
18         1              0          1         0       null              null                null
19         1              0          1         1       null              null                null
20         3              0          1         15      null              null                null
```

Considering different customer data such as the one below, I need to extract the highest priority rule that matches the conditions. I will give you an example below.

Let's consider the following customer data array:

```
Array
(
    [customer] => 44
    [customer_group] => 1
    [store_id] => 0
    [country] => 15
    [subdivision_one] => 421
    [subdivision_two] => 
)
```

The highest priority rule that should be considered is #1. Here's why:

- among all customer groups assigned to that rule, customer_group = 1 is a match;
- the country is matching;
- even if I pass customer and subdivision_one, this rule is matching because for these two attributes I don't have values at all. If I would have a value for customer/subdivision_one with any value, it shouldn't have matched.

I have a query that partially works, giving results only if all attributes involved in the query are matching.

However, *I need to adapt this query so that it would consider an attribute as matched if there is a record available (as in the query) or if there isn't a value available for that attribute.* I hope I was clear enough.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT `r`.*
FROM `rule_attribute_value` `rav`
INNER JOIN `rule` `r`
    ON `rav`.`rule_id` = `r`.`rule_id`
INNER JOIN `rule_attribute` `ra`
    ON `rav`.`attribute_id` = `ra`.`attribute_id`
WHERE
    (`rav`.`store_id` = 0 AND `ra`.`attribute_code` = 'customer' AND `rav`.`value` = 44) OR
    (`rav`.`store_id` = 0 AND `ra`.`attribute_code` = 'customer_group'  AND `rav`.`value` = 1) OR
    (`rav`.`store_id` = 0 AND `ra`.`attribute_code` = 'country' AND `rav`.`value` = 15) OR
    (`rav`.`store_id` = 0 AND `ra`.`attribute_code` = 'subdivision_one' AND `rav`.`value` = 421)
GROUP BY `r`.`rule_id`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `rav`.`attribute_id`) = 4 /* NUMBER OF ATTRIBUTES QUERIED */
ORDER BY `r`.`position` ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Each time a various number of customer attributes will be sent. Sometimes all 6 will have non-empty values, sometimes 5, sometimes 4. I just need to find the highest priority rule that matches the conditions.

Looking forward to hearing back from you.

Comment: Have you tried to make the adjustments in question?

Comment: `AND rav.value = 421` — how does this interact with “there isn't a value available for that attribute”? Is the attribute value NULL, or is the attribute (row) missing entirely?

Comment: I updated the title to hopefully avoid some negative reception. However the question is still unclear (as well as the title), and may be closed for such. I would take a few minutes to reword for clarity and/or provide a minimal matching and non-matching query (using two attributes is sufficient to show).

Comment: The italicized (by me) part isn’t clear. I’ve tried reading it multiple ways. Using different terms to distinguish between search values and (DB) attribute values may help. “..consider an attribute as matched if there is a record available (as in the query) *or* if there isn't a value available for that attributes (*what does this “attributes” mean*?)..”

Comment: The the “attributes” means “search value”, then another `OR 
    (store_id = 0 AND attribute_code = 'the_attr' /* no value limit */)` might be relevant. That assumes the attribute is still ‘defined’ for the rule in the database.

Comment: Thank you for editing my post. It seemed that it was needed to be more clear for all of you. Indeed, too many details were provided maybe. Bottom line, from the rule_attribute_value table, you can consider only rows related to rule ID #1 because that rule should match the provided customer data. The query I provided works if there's 100% matching. The only thing left to do for which I couldn't find a solution is to mark as "matched" those attributes that aren't available for a rule.

Comment: In my example, rule #1 should match because country and customer group were provided and are matching for rule #1. I know I provided subdivision_one and customer as well, but because rule #1 doesn't have records available for these two attributes, it should consider them as matched. If rule #1 would have had subdivision_one = other value than 421 or customer = other value than 44, it shouldn't have matched.

Answer (score 0):

I am still working on finding the most optimized solution for this query, but I think I have found a better way to explain my problem.

Let's consider I just want to find the rule that matches one attribute (the customer). There are three scenarios:

- If a rule has this attribute with the value I am looking for, return the rule;
- If a rule has this attribute, but with a different value than the value I am looking for, return nothing;
- If a rule doesn't have this attribute at all, return the rule.

Here is the query I tried to do, but it's not working as expected. However, the sub-query after the `OR` syntax may help in better understanding what I am looking for.

```
SELECT `r`.*
FROM `rule_attribute_value` `rav`
INNER JOIN `rule` `r`
    ON `rav`.`rule_id` = `r`.`rule_id`
INNER JOIN `rule_attribute` `ra`
    ON `rav`.`attribute_id` = `ra`.`attribute_id`
WHERE
    (`rav`.`store_id` = 0 AND `ra`.`attribute_code` = 'customer'        AND `rav`.`value` = 2) OR (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `coriolan_b2bvariables_rule_attribute_value` `ravs` WHERE `ravs`.`rule_id` = `rav`.`rule_id` AND `rav`.`store_id` = 0 AND `ra`.`attribute_code` = 'customer'))
GROUP BY `r`.`rule_id`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `rav`.`attribute_id`) = 1 /* 1 IS THE NUMBER OF ATTRIBUTES BEING QUERIED */
ORDER BY `r`.`position` ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

This is an example just with one attribute, but I have a total of five attributes. However, I feel that if I will find the solution for one attribute, I can do the rest.